# Connect AWS Glue with SAP HANA

Tags: amazon-web-services, jdbc, aws-glue, hana

Anyone knows how to connect to a public SAP HANA hosted in a Huawei Cloud ECS with AWS Glue?
I'm trying with JDBC but it fails all the time.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.